# Restricting SQL full text search to beginning of text or determining word position

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm using full text search in SQL Server 2008 R2 and it works well. I have a new requirement where I need to be able to search just the first 100 words or so of an `nvarchar(max)` column that is part of a full text index. It doesn't have to be words, but could be first 300 characters or even beginning 20% of the text.

I have a vague recollection that SQL Server full text may maintain the position of the keywords it indexes which is why it is able to support NEAR proximity searches. However, I've been searching and haven't found any way to access this metadata (if it actually exists).

**Ultimately I want to be able to** either (a) restrict a search to the first 100 or so words, or (b) determine the position of where the search term occurs to see if it's in the first 100 words.

If this is not possible with SQL Server fulltext search, my plan is to first use fulltext search to identify the matching rows, and then just on those matching rows, use `LIKE` with `SUBSTRING/LEFT` to see if the search term is in the first 100 words/300 characters/etc of the text.

Comment: Why not just store the first 100 words in a separate column and search that?

Comment: That's essentially what I will likely end up doing but probably with LEFT and LIKE rather than storing in a separate column to keep storage down but mostly so it can be a little more dynamic in case the number/percentage of words/characters needs to be adjusted.  I'll still probably use full text for an initial pass to identify the eligible rows because of how well it performs.